# urlRewrite in web.config to protect aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms, web-config

I created a custom login/authentication page.
When the user authenticates and is valid, my site:
Response.Redirects("destinationpage.aspx");

Because I'm not using Forms Authentication, I need another way to protect "destinationpage.aspx".

Is there a way to use urlRewrite in web.config to redirect users to "customlogin.aspx" to authenticate before being able to reach "destinationpage.aspx"?

Comment: If you look at [Best way to do authorization in webforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237869/best-way-to-do-authorization-in-webforms) it describes how to use the location and authorization configuration to prevent users from accessing a page that they aren't authorized to see. You should not rely on rewriting URL's to achieve this.

Comment: that's a great resource, but i cannot authenticate through forms authentication, which is why i asked this question.

could I, after authenticating user, create a custom role and add the user that was just authenticated into that custom role? then, i just set up a separate web.config and allow users from that custom role.

Comment: Authorization in ASP.NET isn't dependent on how you perform authentication, so Forms Authentication isn't necessary. Perhaps you should show us how you're performing custom authentication.

Comment: I'm using 

PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(user, pass);

and validating against AD.

if (isValid)
Response.Redirect("destinationpage.aspx");

Comment: And how does the user enter their credentials? Do they enter their username and password into a form on your site?

Comment: yes. i made a custom LoginForm.aspx where they enter credentials.

Comment: Then in this case we can avoid writing a custom membership provider. Have a look at [Forms Authentication and Active Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572663), the question has a good example of using Active Directory with Forms Authentication (which is what you're doing, but he wired it up properly with `AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`). Then for custom roles (instead of AD) look at [Custom Role Provider with ActiveDirectory Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307063). If roles aren't necessarily, see my first comment for how to deny unauthenticated

Comment: thanks for the resources. it helped me come up with another way of doing this.